# Script error while using xml test runner in python

Tags: python, xml, unit-testing

I'm using xml test runner for generating a xml report after unit tests:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XmlTestRunner

However, I just an error:

> SyntaxError ( ('future feature unicode_literals is not defined'

If you take a look at the script you can see the line:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

What is the problem with the `unicode_literals` import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using a version of Python older than 2.6.0. The `unicode_literals` future import first appeared in 2.6.0.

Upgrade your Python to a more recent version if you want the script to run.